# Calling functions from a spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I'm starting to learn Google Apps Script and trying to complete "Your First Custom Function" tutorial. Maybe something has changed and they forgot to update the tutorial? When I type `=in2mm(10)` in a cell, it shows `#NAME` and `Unknown function name` popup is displayed.

So how do I call my own functions from a spreadsheet formula?

Answer (score 4):

run your function just once through the editor's menu to be sure it is saved correctly then in the spreadsheet use it like this in cell B1 for example if A1 contains a numeric value :

```
=in2mm(A1)
```

or if you prefer, just like in your example : `=in2mm(10)` and it will show 254 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by deleting "inNum" in the function claiming part "function in2mm(inNum)", running it without any parameter in the spreadsheet once and getting THINKING... and ERROR, and retyping "inNum" in the function claiming part "function in2mm(inNum)", running and getting THINKING and correct result. Maybe it's the encoding issue when you copy and paste from the web page directly.